# using the NASM assembler in RadASM on windows

Tags: assembly, installation, nasm

I've been trying to use the NASM assembler on RadASM but every time I try to choose an assembler my only option is 'html' shown below:
[image: image showing HTML is my only option]

I've tried putting them both on the PATH and running as administrator, other peoples queries, even darn chatGPT, but I can't seem to figure it out, my **NASM version is 2.16rc12** compiled on Dec 7 2022, and my **RadASM version is v2.2.2.3**, is there a third-party plugin or some dependencies that are required in the installation process? Thanks!

Comment: After installing RadASM, download the RadASM Assembly programming (07-08-2008) pack from http://www.assembly.com.br/ and follow the instructions in the readme.txt file in the zip file.